# What is the best way to send and display logs for easy access and monitoring?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, filebeat

I would love to know the best way to display logs for a system of mine. I receive logs once a day in bulk (the logs are not needed in real time) and I was wondering, what is the most efficient way to send and display them for quick and easy monitoring. I read into a few possibilities such as - Filebeat, Logstash, sending the logs to ElasticSearch / Kibana with post requests in python, etc. Any recommendations are appreciated :)

Comment: i would just use scp to copy them to whereever you want

Comment: I would rather a more automated situation though.

Comment: maybe i think too simple but you could use cron to automatically issue the copiing

Comment: i´m used to work with logfiles with commandline, you can pretty much extract anything you want, a friend of mine uses greylog to view log files, maybe thats sth for you

Answer (score 0):

you can use the exec input plugin provided by logstash to run commands ( i.e: to get the log files with scp for instance ) and then, use the cron parameter to set how often you want to retrieve the logs.

more: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-exec.html